# Is there any way to know how many characters are retained or visible after text-overflow:ellipsis and overflow:hidden is applied?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a string of email addresses separated by a delimiter ';' and want to show all text as it is. Also  want to clip any overflow text over one line and then show +count of emails ids remaining that user did not get to see(driven by some @ and ; character logic). Is there any way to know how many characters are retained/ or even removed from the HTML text after the it is clipped ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is your criteria exactly, but here is an example of how it can be calculated:

```js
var span = document.getElementById("text");
var countSpan = document.getElementById("count");
var orig = span.innerText;
var vis = orig;

while(vis.length && span.scrollWidth > parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(span).width))
{
  vis = vis.slice(0,-1);
  span.innerText = vis + "....";
}
span.innerText = orig;

var visibleText = vis;
var truncatedText = orig.replace(new RegExp("^" + vis.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&')), "");
var visibleCleanLessText;
var visibleCleanMoreText;
var truncatedCleanLessText;
var truncatedCleanMoreText;
if (truncatedText === "" || truncatedText.substr(0, 1) == ";")
{
  visibleCleanLessText = vis;
  visibleCleanMoreText = vis;
  truncatedCleanLessText = truncatedText.substr(1);
  truncatedCleanMoreText = truncatedCleanLessText;
}
else
{
  var m = vis.match(/;([^;]*)$/);
  visibleCleanLessText = m ? vis.replace(/;[^;]*$/, "") : "";
  visibleCleanMoreText = vis + (truncatedText.match(/^([^;]*);/) || ["",""])[1];
  truncatedCleanMoreText = (m ? m[1] : vis) + truncatedText;
  truncatedCleanLessText = truncatedText.replace(/^[^;]*;/, "");
}
var truncatedCount = truncatedCleanMoreText === "" ? 0 : truncatedCleanMoreText.split(";").length;
if (truncatedCount)
{
  countSpan.innerText = "+" + truncatedCount;
  span.title = orig;
}

console.log("orig              ", orig);
console.log("visible           ", vis);
console.log("truncated         ", truncatedText);
console.log("visibleCleanLess  ", visibleCleanLessText);
console.log("truncatedCleanMore", truncatedCleanMoreText);
console.log("visibleCleanMore  ", visibleCleanMoreText);
console.log("truncatedCleanLess", truncatedCleanLessText);
```

```css
div
{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.truncate
{
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.count:empty
{
  display: none;
}
.count
{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 90%;
  left: -0.5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  padding: 0.1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="text" class="truncate">email1@example.com;email2@example.com;email3@example.com;email4@example.com</span>
  <span id="count" class="count"></span>
</div>
```